# Unable to dynamically use Font Awesome icon in submit button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, font-awesome

I am able to use a font-awesome icon as button text using the following HTML:

```
<button tabindex="4" type="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg disabled" onclick="sendemail(); return false;"><i class="fa fa-paper-plane" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
```

However, I need to do this dynamically using JQuery:

```
var contact_form = $('div#contact.pbmodal div.modal-dialog div.modal-content form');
var submit_button = contact_form.find('button#submit');
submit_button.text('<i class="fa fa-paper-plane" aria-hidden="true"></i>');
```

The above JQuery outputs the font-awesome element as a text tag, i.e. the button says `<i class="fa fa-paper-plane" aria-hidden="true"></i>` instead of showing the actual icon.

Comment: Please read jQuery documentation to find out the difference between `text()` and `html()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `.html()` instead to add HTML tags to your DOM, else the `.text()` will add the code as text :

```
submit_button.html('<i class="fa fa-paper-plane" aria-hidden="true"></i>');
```

Hope this helps.

```js
var submit_button = $("#submit");

submit_button.html('<i class="fa fa-paper-plane" aria-hidden="true"></i>');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<button tabindex="4" type="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg disabled" onclick="sendemail(); return false;"></button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this line:

```
submit_button.text('<i class="fa fa-paper-plane" aria-hidden="true"></i>');
```

to

```
submit_button.after('<i class="fa fa-paper-plane" aria-hidden="true"></i>');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a button only with a icon the better is to add the font class into the button :

```
submit_button.addClass('fa fa-paper-plane');
```

You button will look at:

```
<button tabindex="4" type="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg disabled fa fa-paper-plane" onclick="sendemail(); return false;"></button>
```

This is a jsFiddle with the previous HTML

https://jsfiddle.net/s0dw6yp4/1/

Answer (score 0):

Change `submit_button.text('...')` to `submit_button.html('...')`

Text inserts the exact `text` you entered while `html` interprets the html-code.